# Extracting part of string that came from beautifulsoup

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string

I have this string which came from BeautifulSoup:

```
<span class="move-text-component vertical-move-list-clickable"><!-- -->

 abc6

 <!-- --> <!-- --></span>
```

How can I extract the abc6 text knowing that it can be any substring with 2-6 characters/numbers/hyphens (characters are both capitalized and not) and I would think that it has a new line character behind and after always as here.
How can I do this using any method you find appropriate? (regex, beautifulsoup, etc)

**edit:** this is the exact string printed as list to show \n characters:

```
['<span class="move-text-component vertical-move-list-clickable"><!-- -->\n\n  d4\n\n  <!-- --> <!-- --></span>']
```

Comment: Is there really a dot before `span` or is it a typo?

Comment: No, there is a / in the 2nd part. It wasn't a typo, I wrote it because without it stackoverflow was taking it at code and not showing correctly. It should be <span... and </span> at the end.

Comment: Then [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54169938/edit) accordingly

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/pCLdpJ/1) OK for you?

Comment: That one doesn't work correctly. But @pirate answer is working fine. Thanks for the website reference anyway seems useful.

Comment: Beautiful soup has .text.strip() that will do the job for you. see the example below!

Comment: How doesn't it work correctly? It matches `abc6` inside `<span..> ... </span>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with regex:

```
<.+>\n\n(.+)\n\n<.+>
```

And extract the group in ()

In Python you will have to write it like this:

```
import re
re.search(".+\n\n(.+)\n\n.+", text).group(1)
```

The `.` matches any character
The `+` matches between one and unlimited times
The `()` is to select group
The `.group(1)` in the end is to take the first match that is in the `()`

Comment: @pirateSomehow this gives noneType has no attribute group. the exact string is :  

['<span class="move-text-component vertical-move-list-clickable"><!-- -->\n\n  d4\n\n  <!-- --> <!-- --></span>']
Can you explain a bit more about how the group and the ".+" work please?

Comment: Yes, the new one worked! Thanks
Can you just give a short explanation if you have time so that I can understand it a bit better?
the .+ and the group(1) parts

Comment: Also, is there a way to take the spaces at the beggining end of the selected text during the re.search? instead of slicing the string after.

Comment: @Miguel You can add spaces inside the regex with \s, like this: .+\n\n\s+(.+)\n\n.+

Comment: This is correct, but I think it complicates the task. BeautifulSoup has tools to get the data without turning to regex :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need other tools than BeautifulSoup. Just use .text.strip() :)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = """
<span class="move-text-component vertical-move-list-clickable"><!-- -->\n\n  d4\n\n  <!-- --> <!-- --></span>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

data = soup.find('span', class_ ="move-text-component vertical-move-list-clickable")

print(data.text.strip())
```

Results

[image]